# Return total number of files within a folder using PHP

Tags: php, file, count, directory

Is there a better/simpler way to find the number of images in a directory and output them to a variable?

```
function dirCount($dir) {
  $x = 0;
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if (isImage($file)) {$x = $x + 1}
  }
  return $x;
}
```

This seems like such a long way of doing this, is there no simpler way?

**Note:** The isImage() function returns true if the file is an image.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out the Standard PHP Library (aka SPL) for DirectoryIterator:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir');
foreach($dir as $file ){
  $x += (isImage($file)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

(FYI there is an undocumented function called iterator_count() but probably best not to rely on it for now I would imagine. And you'd need to filter out unseen stuff like . and .. anyway.)

Comment: That's what I was about to post. I think your solution is the way to go.

Comment: AWSOME!  Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 15):

This will give you the count of what is in your dir. I'll leave the part about counting only images to you as I am about to fallll aaasssllleeelppppppzzzzzzzzzzzzz.

```
iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('path/to/dir/'));
```

Answer (score 5):

i do it like this:

```
$files = scandir($dir);
$x = count($files);
echo $x;
```

but it also counts the . and ..

Comment: It also retrieves folders, so as far as I know you should loop through the `$files` array and check if it's a file using `is_file`.

Answer (score 4):

The aforementioned code

```
$count = count(glob("*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}"));
```

is your best best, but the {jpg,png,gif} bit will only work if you append the `GLOB_BRACE` flag on the end:

```
$count = count(glob("*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE));
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use `glob`...

```
$count = 0;
foreach (glob("*.*") as $file) {
    if (isImage($file)) ++$count;
}
```

or, I'm not sure how well this would suit your needs, but you could do this:

```
$count = count(glob("*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of the SPL to filter the contents of a `DirectoryIterator` using your `isImage` function by extending the abstract `FilterIterator` class.

```
class ImageIterator extends FilterIterator {

    public function __construct($path)
    {
        parent::__construct(new DirectoryIterator($path));
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        return isImage($this->getInnerIterator());
    }
}
```

You could then use `iterator_count` (or implement the `Countable` interface and use the native `count` function) to determine the number of images. For example:

```
$images = new ImageIterator('/path/to/images');
printf('Found %d images!', iterator_count($images));
```

Using this approach, depending on how you need to use this code, it might make more sense to move the `isImage` function into the `ImageIterator` class to have everything neatly wrapped up in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to get the count for all types of files in one directory in Laravel

```
   $dir = public_path('img/');
    $files = glob($dir . '*.*');

    if ( $files !== false )
    {
        $total_count = count( $files );
        return $totalCount;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems about as simple as you can get it.  I can't think of a shorter way to it in either PHP or Perl.

You might be able to a system / exec command involving ls, wc, and grep if you are using Linux depending how complex isImage() is.

Regardless, I think what you have is quite sufficient.  You only have to write the function once.

Comment: I try to avoid System and Exec (security first!), but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: If you find that your isImage() function and current method is slow I think that doing a ls and piping it to wc -l might be faster. I would only do that IF your current method is slow though, because your right about the security reasons for not using system/exec.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to return a count of ALL files in a directory except . and ..

```
return count(glob("/path/to/file/[!\.]*"));
```

Here is [a good list of glob filters](http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/) for file matching purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nfiles = glob("/path/to/file/[!\\.]*");

if ($nfiles !== FALSE){

    return count($nfiles);

} else {

    return 0;

}
```