# How to find fast the number of files in directory?

Tags: php

I have thousands log files in a few directories in my system. Mostly I need to know just number of these files in directory. I fear that this attitude:

```
$files = count(scandir("logs")) - 2;
```

Is not very effective (memory, filesystem). I am considering some global counter (incremented after file is added), unless there is some other effective way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return total number of files within a folder using PHP.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224408/return-total-number-of-files-within-a-folder-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are my totals when scanning around 30 folders, with ~5000 files each.
Can't find a faster way than `scandir` except caching results (in memcached or something).

```
echo count(scandir('logs/'))-2; // 0.140 sec

echo system('find "logs/ | wc -l'); // 0.300 sec

echo system('ls -l logs/ | wc -l'); // 1.200 sec

echo count(glob('logs/*',GLOB_NOSORT)); // 1.800 sec
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, none of the other answers actually address performance, and this is specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call system listing of files:

```
$files = exec('ls logs | wc -l');
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just for curiosity - is there some similar command in Windows systems?

Comment: The problem with this: not portable.

Comment: It is not portable but has the best performance I think. However if we have an unix server, it will be a good solution.

Comment: you can do this with backtick operator without the exec command just echo ls -l with in backticks

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = count(glob("logs/*",GLOB_NOSORT));
```

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Really? To produce a large array in PHP - just because of one number?

Comment: @Jan Well, how can you enumerate something that you do not see?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with opendir/readdir?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            ++$i;
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also considering this "unary counter" solution: After each file is added, run this command

```
file_put_contents("counter_myDir","1",FILE_APPEND);
```

Then I would have some few kB more in each directory (there are just a few dirs, it is ok) and the reading seems to be very effective and portable, too:

```
$files = filesize("counter_myDir");
```

Can you please compare this to other solutions suggested here? I really need to know the number of files as effectively as possible.

Comment: +1 not a bad idea, if you want to do it this way, you can. Just make sure to provide a fallback if a counter file is accidentally deleted (run one of the solutions here and recreate it with new data).