# Total files in subdirectories only where with strlen is a certain length

Tags: php, dir, strlen

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this one.

What I need to achieve is to scan a directory with subdirectories to return a total file count where the character count of the filename is 48 characters in length.

So something like:

scan `c:\blah` for files
but only return a result if the filename is 48 characters
then add the total of all files found in c:\blah
which would result in `c:\blah` having (example) 3 files

The filenames do not need to be shown, just to total number of files meeting this criteria.

Comment: Checkout 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895343/php-count-total-files-in-directory-and-subdirectory-function


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224408/return-total-number-of-files-within-a-folder-using-php?rq=1

Comment: @user1758246 Please mark answers as accepted that worked for you here and on your other questions. There is a check mark next to the upvote/downvote arrows on each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$length = 48;
$directory = 'C:/';

$total = 0;

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $fn)
{
    if ($fn->isDir() && strlen($fn->getFilename()) == $length)
    {
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($fn->getPathname()) as $sfn)
        {
            if (!$sfn->isDot())
                $total++;
        }
    }
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: You know what.. that's perfect, but I missed a very important note out - its on a remote server. Example \\thisserver\d$\another\folder\here

Comment: Right, so I get that I can go remote once I have access.. but how to go sub sub directories? This (correct me if I'm wrong) only goes one deep.